# Unable to login to Postgres due to 'connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused'

Tags: postgresql, ssl

**UPDATE: This issue has been solved and I have provided the solution at the end of this post.**
The problem was with the way I was creating my keys as well as my pg_hba.conf file. Please follow the exact steps mentioned in the official PostgreSQL document.

---

## Original post:

I am a student and I am learning about PostgreSQL. I have installed postgresql version 16 on my system and I am trying to connect to my own [127.0.0.1](https://127.0.0.1) loopback address using SSL certificates. The issue that I am facing is:

> psql: error: connection to server at "[127.0.0.1](https://127.0.0.1)", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Due to this, I am unable to login to Postgres even with running 'sudo su postgres' & then 'psql', as I am shown the same error as above. This has started happening since I tried to connect to Postgres using SSL using the following steps:

```
1. openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
2. openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key
3. chown postgres:postgres server.key
chmod 0600 server.key
4. openssl req -new -key server.key -days 3650 -out server.crt -x509 -subj "/CN=IP OR HOSTNAME"
cp server.crt root.crt
5. chown postgres:postgres server.crt
chmod 0600 server.crt
chown postgres:postgres root.crt
chmod 0600 root.crt
```

The following changes were made to postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*' 
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = '/etc/postgresql/16/main/root.crt'
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.crt'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.key'
```

Changes made to pg_hba.conf:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
hostssl    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

The output of 'systemctl status postgresql':

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2023-10-25 15:38:09 IST; 2min 7s ago
   Main PID: 54225 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 9ms
```

Please help me understand where I am going wrong with setting up my SSL configurations. Please mind that I am successfully login to my system if I comment out the SSL settings from the postgresql.conf but if I keep it on, I am locked out of Postgres.

If any more information is required, please tell me.

Edit: Postgres log file contains the following:

```
2023-10-25 15:03:39.641 IST [33874] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg23.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0, 64-bit
2023-10-25 15:03:39.642 IST [33874] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-10-25 15:03:39.644 IST [33874] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-10-25 15:03:39.659 IST [33877] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-10-25 15:03:28 IST
2023-10-25 15:03:39.675 IST [33874] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-10-25 15:04:59.402 IST [33874] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-10-25 15:04:59.416 IST [33874] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-10-25 15:04:59.448 IST [33874] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 33880) exited with exit code 1
2023-10-25 15:04:59.524 IST [33875] LOG:  shutting down
2023-10-25 15:04:59.528 IST [33875] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-10-25 15:04:59.563 IST [33875] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 39 buffers (0.2%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.016 s, sync=0.007 s, total=0.039 s; sync files=11, longest=0.003 s, average=0.001 s; distance=203 kB, estimate=203 kB; lsn=0/1520FA8, redo lsn=0/1520FA8
2023-10-25 15:04:59.618 IST [33874] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-10-25 15:05:00.468 IST [35141] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg23.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0, 64-bit
2023-10-25 15:05:00.469 IST [35141] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-10-25 15:05:00.469 IST [35141] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-10-25 15:05:00.474 IST [35141] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-10-25 15:05:00.513 IST [35145] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-10-25 15:04:59 IST
2023-10-25 15:05:00.555 IST [35141] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-10-25 15:06:39.500 IST [35782] postgres@postgres ERROR:  syntax error at or near "service" at character 1
2023-10-25 15:06:39.500 IST [35782] postgres@postgres STATEMENT:  service postgresql status
    ;
2023-10-25 15:06:42.863 IST [35782] postgres@postgres LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2023-10-25 15:10:00.614 IST [35143] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2023-10-25 15:10:00.848 IST [35143] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 5 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.210 s, sync=0.007 s, total=0.235 s; sync files=4, longest=0.005 s, average=0.002 s; distance=2 kB, estimate=2 kB; lsn=0/1521950, redo lsn=0/1521918
2023-10-25 15:12:01.170 IST [35141] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-10-25 15:12:01.174 IST [35141] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-10-25 15:12:01.190 IST [35141] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 35148) exited with exit code 1
2023-10-25 15:12:01.201 IST [35143] LOG:  shutting down
2023-10-25 15:12:01.204 IST [35143] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-10-25 15:12:01.218 IST [35143] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 0 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.003 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.018 s; sync files=0, longest=0.000 s, average=0.000 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=2 kB; lsn=0/1521A00, redo lsn=0/1521A00
2023-10-25 15:12:01.252 IST [35141] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-10-25 15:12:02.125 IST [39898] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.crt": ee key too small
2023-10-25 15:12:02.138 IST [39898] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 15:12:10.831 IST [39983] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.crt": ee key too small
2023-10-25 15:12:10.832 IST [39983] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 15:15:43.117 IST [41890] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.crt": ee key too small
2023-10-25 15:15:43.118 IST [41890] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 15:17:05.787 IST [42585] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.crt": ee key too small
2023-10-25 15:17:05.788 IST [42585] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 15:17:45.782 IST [42977] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg23.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0, 64-bit
2023-10-25 15:17:45.783 IST [42977] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-10-25 15:17:45.783 IST [42977] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-10-25 15:17:45.790 IST [42977] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-10-25 15:17:45.803 IST [42977] LOG:  hostssl record cannot match because SSL is disabled
2023-10-25 15:17:45.803 IST [42977] HINT:  Set ssl = on in postgresql.conf.
2023-10-25 15:17:45.803 IST [42977] CONTEXT:  line 125 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf"
2023-10-25 15:17:45.803 IST [42977] LOG:  invalid value for clientcert: "1"
2023-10-25 15:17:45.803 IST [42977] CONTEXT:  line 125 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf"
2023-10-25 15:17:45.803 IST [42977] LOG:  hostssl record cannot match because SSL is disabled
2023-10-25 15:17:45.803 IST [42977] HINT:  Set ssl = on in postgresql.conf.
2023-10-25 15:17:45.803 IST [42977] CONTEXT:  line 133 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf"
2023-10-25 15:17:45.804 IST [42977] FATAL:  could not load /etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf
2023-10-25 15:17:45.819 IST [42977] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 15:18:05.824 IST [43140] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg23.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0, 64-bit
2023-10-25 15:18:05.825 IST [43140] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-10-25 15:18:05.832 IST [43140] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-10-25 15:18:05.842 IST [43140] LOG:  hostssl record cannot match because SSL is disabled
2023-10-25 15:18:05.842 IST [43140] HINT:  Set ssl = on in postgresql.conf.
2023-10-25 15:18:05.842 IST [43140] CONTEXT:  line 125 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf"
2023-10-25 15:18:05.842 IST [43140] LOG:  invalid value for clientcert: "1"
2023-10-25 15:18:05.842 IST [43140] CONTEXT:  line 125 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf"
2023-10-25 15:18:05.842 IST [43140] LOG:  hostssl record cannot match because SSL is disabled
2023-10-25 15:18:05.842 IST [43140] HINT:  Set ssl = on in postgresql.conf.
2023-10-25 15:18:05.842 IST [43140] CONTEXT:  line 133 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf"
2023-10-25 15:18:05.843 IST [43140] FATAL:  could not load /etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf
2023-10-25 15:18:05.849 IST [43140] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 15:19:05.844 IST [43590] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg23.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0, 64-bit
2023-10-25 15:19:05.845 IST [43590] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-10-25 15:19:05.854 IST [43590] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-10-25 15:19:05.865 IST [43590] LOG:  hostssl record cannot match because SSL is disabled
2023-10-25 15:19:05.865 IST [43590] HINT:  Set ssl = on in postgresql.conf.
2023-10-25 15:19:05.865 IST [43590] CONTEXT:  line 134 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/pg_hba.conf"
2023-10-25 15:19:05.885 IST [43593] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-10-25 15:12:01 IST
2023-10-25 15:19:05.920 IST [43590] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-10-25 15:24:05.981 IST [43591] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2023-10-25 15:24:06.047 IST [43591] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.018 s, sync=0.007 s, total=0.066 s; sync files=2, longest=0.004 s, average=0.004 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB; lsn=0/1521AE8, redo lsn=0/1521AB0
2023-10-25 15:29:38.483 IST [43590] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-10-25 15:29:38.491 IST [43590] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-10-25 15:29:38.506 IST [43590] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 43596) exited with exit code 1
2023-10-25 15:29:38.507 IST [43591] LOG:  shutting down
2023-10-25 15:29:38.515 IST [43591] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-10-25 15:29:38.562 IST [43591] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 0 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.002 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.055 s; sync files=0, longest=0.000 s, average=0.000 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB; lsn=0/1521B98, redo lsn=0/1521B98
2023-10-25 15:29:38.591 IST [43590] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-10-25 15:29:39.138 IST [49300] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.crt": ee key too small
2023-10-25 15:29:39.138 IST [49300] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 15:38:09.779 IST [54224] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.crt": ee key too small
2023-10-25 15:38:09.780 IST [54224] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 16:24:16.729 IST [78951] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.crt": ee key too small
2023-10-25 16:24:16.730 IST [78951] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 16:38:53.513 IST [87038] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg23.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0, 64-bit
2023-10-25 16:38:53.514 IST [87038] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Address already in use
2023-10-25 16:38:53.514 IST [87038] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2023-10-25 16:38:53.514 IST [87038] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2023-10-25 16:38:53.515 IST [87038] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2023-10-25 16:38:53.526 IST [87038] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 16:39:14.537 IST [87202] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg23.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0, 64-bit
2023-10-25 16:39:14.539 IST [87202] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Address already in use
2023-10-25 16:39:14.539 IST [87202] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2023-10-25 16:39:14.539 IST [87202] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2023-10-25 16:39:14.539 IST [87202] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2023-10-25 16:39:14.554 IST [87202] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 16:40:27.739 IST [87769] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg23.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0, 64-bit
2023-10-25 16:40:27.740 IST [87769] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Address already in use
2023-10-25 16:40:27.740 IST [87769] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2023-10-25 16:40:27.740 IST [87769] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2023-10-25 16:40:27.741 IST [87769] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2023-10-25 16:40:27.752 IST [87769] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 16:40:36.724 IST [87844] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg23.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0, 64-bit
2023-10-25 16:40:36.725 IST [87844] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Address already in use
2023-10-25 16:40:36.725 IST [87844] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2023-10-25 16:40:36.725 IST [87844] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2023-10-25 16:40:36.726 IST [87844] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2023-10-25 16:40:36.735 IST [87844] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-10-25 17:03:30.466 IST [99511] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.crt": ee key too small
2023-10-25 17:03:30.467 IST [99511] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

## UPDATE 2

I generated the certificates and keys using the [official documentation of Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/ssl-tcp.html#SSL-CERTIFICATE-CREATION) but I am still facing the same 'FATAL' error as earlier.

The logs are:

```
i am getting "psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?"

the log file says:
2023-10-28 11:08:23.232 IST [1124103] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.crt": no start line
2023-10-28 11:08:23.232 IST [1124103] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

my postgresql.conf file is as follows:

```
# - SSL -
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = '/etc/postgresql/16/main/root.crt'
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.crt'
#ssl_crl_file = ''
#ssl_crl_dir = ''
ssl_key_file = '/etc/postgresql/16/main/server.key'
```

I understand that the log says that there is an issue with the server.crt file but the output of ls -l shows that it exists as follows:

```
postgres@yashanand:/etc/postgresql/16/main$ ls -l
total 100
-rw------- 1 root     root      1342 Oct 26 00:05 client.crt
-rw------- 1 root     root      1708 Oct 26 00:05 client.key
drwxr-xr-x 2 postgres postgres  4096 Oct 25 15:03 conf.d
-rw-rw-r-- 1 postgres postgres   424 Oct 25 11:51 dhparam.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres   315 Oct 25 15:03 environment
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres   143 Oct 25 15:03 pg_ctl.conf
-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres  5986 Oct 28 11:04 pg_hba.conf
-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres  2640 Oct 25 15:03 pg_ident.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres 29961 Oct 26 00:10 postgresql.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 postgres postgres  4136 Oct 28 10:53 root.crt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 postgres postgres  3359 Oct 28 10:53 root.csr
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  1704 Oct 28 10:53 root.key
-rw------- 1 root     root        41 Oct 26 00:05 root.srl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 postgres postgres     0 Oct 28 10:52 server.crt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 postgres postgres  3359 Oct 28 10:52 server.csr
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  1704 Oct 28 10:52 server.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres   317 Oct 25 15:03 start.conf
```

Comment: `systemctl status postgresql` is pretty useless.  Look in the postgresql server log file to see what is actually going on.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that.. I have edited the post and added the log contents. I will start working on trying to understand what the issue is from the logs, I request you to please help me by doing the same...

Comment: @jjanes Thank you for your suggestion. After going through the logs, I have found that there seems to be some issue with the size of the key that is being generated (not sure what that means). So for now, I will try to create a new SSL certificate because that is the core of my problem from what I have understood from the logs.

Comment: I get the same 'ee key too small' error when I follow your creation steps, but it works when I follow the ones given here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/ssl-tcp.html#SSL-CERTIFICATE-CREATION.  Maybe 'genrsa' is just not the right way to do this kind of thing.  Where did you get your steps from?

Comment: It looks like 1024 is just too short.  Try 2048.

Comment: The steps that I followed were from here: https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/PlatformAnalytics/en-us/Content/configure_ssl_pgsql_consumer.htm
I'll try with 2048 now, thanks

Comment: @jjanes I have created the certificates and keys using the method provided in the documentation but I am still getting the same error that is mentioned in the post. Please check the updated post with the new logs...

Comment: The output of `ls -l` that you've posted shows that `server.crt` is an empty file (size = 0 bytes).

Comment: This issue has been solved! I recreated the server.cert and now I am able to successfuly SSL into postgresql. Note to self and anyone else that may come across this post: Always follow the official documents instead of some random guide on the internet....

Comment: Please [post an answer](/help/self-answer) instead of editing the question to include the solution